# How to get image from image uploader file path and bind in custom collection? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have created custom image uploader to upload category icon. I also created custom model and controller for the same.

After click on save button image will save in pub/static folder successfully.

Now, I want to get that image in frontend. How to done it?

Comment: Where did you save the icon file name? Did you use any custom Database Table?

Comment: No, I am not using any custom database table. I just added one Attribute using InstallData.php in Setup Folder.

Comment: I also save file in pub/media folder. I just want to display that file in frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a helper class and use your help to get category icon Url as described below.

I assume your custom extension name is "**Vendor_Module**". I also assume that your custom category attribute name is "**caticon**"

**step 1)** Create a helper class **Data.php** under ***/app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/***

File : **Data.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data
    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    // category attribute name
    const ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "caticon";

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Icon image URL by category
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category)
    {
        $image = $category->getData(self::ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

        return $this->getUrl($image);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl($value)
    {
        $url = false;
        if ($value) {
            if (is_string($value)) {
                $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                    ) . 'pub/media/' . $value;
            } else {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while getting the image url.')
                );
            }
        }

        return $url;
    }


}
```

**step 2)** Run Di compile commands from CLI

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**step 3)** How to use your helper to get category icon url in a phtml file.

Sample example  phmtl file:

```
    <?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
    $_helper       = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');
    $categoryId    = 10;
    $category      = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
    $categoryIconUrl =  $_helper->getUrl($category->getCaticon()); // i.e get icon Attribute
    // or you can use below line of code to get icon image by category object
   // $categoryIconUrl =  $_helper->getImageUrl($category)
    ?>                            
    <img src="<?php echo $categoryIconUrl?>" />
```